# Malformed Session ID Cookie

Tags: perl, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, mojolicious, ibm-watson

```
Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=836cfc64b5856712b040a0b1b3bf4237; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Watson-DPAT=gBJQjAG%2FYflxpHKCwJVswQPEBuUmikj38zzFm8UZNTbOERxbeXS4WVxBIT5JetJBkeO1RT16PNz6%2BI17oFrEqvxjny%2FifZRorvBxXVzDmFkRpfRLxxj6ZNvFCvuRL1DtfW3nL8Ne1QDwpuKQmNt8%2BD9vFk7bGjlaziHT0ZFhNffWJT7FRCWbuJAyjKd%2BQui2WTIl6B8KglPi6GG1buh5UPDE%2Bc8OvrqyAfJRfYOApRdx7kHhtHdxIV7g%2FzNExXhafScqxi4cWEa5Kg9YGcypr8SIO%2FD7WOq0KyERHUDkbZatH53CCii25it5XD0plnt3cVc4bWs8tXkMT82V9DwCYULto64L%2BgNh30iTpyv72xOIfHeZTt2KISfhXMy6z86ueaJZzNd4nS6rwc7s2E8ldxwYLXrCU996xsLmzPYbGSzaeFLplG7c%2BCxzTlAll5fn8eMMbGn30W%2BrXLNtcaJ3lRK2nvzQCim1GhMdqoOvOcSvPWiJoVBrF8lc75eGSr8C%2Fovq20fOk3NDw4f0UPfBEGZYuAtXjonU7QdRhSgLRXxKyGvcYHEWeWUOQ2kvtI2m%2FRD%2BMRx9384p1v6uu8XfaU16IqoidV0Vew3MLPW4fxcOWRqnWKy0iIYbIJrWVcigloIy%2FNxgO7oHW7aacgH1u8IluAURz5AiE1Bej4l%2FjAI91IUTEssbg6fsXd3AqmlkixDglDJBgTEtMoXhXVyDjvJSaVUqdFTokP3YcRNhlTzqDQ3vG8txTLzECsyQHZ7DgWp%2B98P3zjvtad9xB%2BDzXhF4CaUB7ve99bWO5FO1DU3KRhx7pEAKGselDCoxTOkjIhEMMJbeQrbC1QWJ4uR9KlBPBdIbShd3; path=/speech-to-text/api; secure; HttpOnly
```

The request to create the Speech to Text session works.

```
{
   "recognize": "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/sessions/836cfc64b5856712b040a0b1b3bf4237/recognize",
   "recognizeWS": "wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/sessions/836cfc64b5856712b040a0b1b3bf4237/recognize",
   "observe_result": "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/sessions/836cfc64b5856712b040a0b1b3bf4237/observe_result",
   "session_id": "836cfc64b5856712b040a0b1b3bf4237",
   "new_session_uri": "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/sessions/836cfc64b5856712b040a0b1b3bf4237"
}
```

Then I try to get the status of the session to make sure the state is "initialized" but I get a "Malformed Session ID Cookie" error.

```
GET /speech-to-text/api/v1/sessions/836cfc64b5856712b040a0b1b3bf4237/recognize HTTP/1.1\x0d
Content-Length: 0\x0d
Accept-Encoding: gzip\x0d
Authorization: Basic OGIyMTk0MDYtYWYzYS00YTFhLWExYmMtZDA3ZjNlNTY2Y2JmOm1lYmpBaG1ndkhMSw==\x0d
Cookie: SESSIONID=836cfc64b5856712b040a0b1b3bf4237; Watson-DPAT=gBJQjAG%2FYflxpHKCwJVswQPEBuUmikj38zzFm8UZNTbOERxbeXS4WVxBIT5JetJBkeO1RT16PNz6%2BI17oFrEqvxjny%2FifZRorvBxXVzDmFkRpfRLxxj6ZNvFCvuRL1DtfW3nL8Ne1QDwpuKQmNt8%2BD9vFk7bGjlaziHT0ZFhNffWJT7FRCWbuJAyjKd%2BQui2WTIl6B8KglPi6GG1buh5UPDE%2Bc8OvrqyAfJRfYOApRdx7kHhtHdxIV7g%2FzNExXhafScqxi4cWEa5Kg9YGcypr8SIO%2FD7WOq0KyERHUDkbZatH53CCii25it5XD0plnt3cVc4bWs8tXkMT82V9DwCYULto64L%2BgNh30iTpyv72xOIfHeZTt2KISfhXMy6z86ueaJZzNd4nS6rwc7s2E8ldxwYLXrCU996xsLmzPYbGSzaeFLplG7c%2BCxzTlAll5fn8eMMbGn30W%2BrXLNtcaJ3lRK2nvzQCim1GhMdqoOvOcSvPWiJoVBrF8lc75eGSr8C%2Fovq20fOk3NDw4f0UPfBEGZYuAtXjonU7QdRhSgLRXxKyGvcYHEWeWUOQ2kvtI2m%2FRD%2BMRx9384p1v6uu8XfaU16IqoidV0Vew3MLPW4fxcOWRqnWKy0iIYbIJrWVcigloIy%2FNxgO7oHW7aacgH1u8IluAURz5AiE1Bej4l%2FjAI91IUTEssbg6fsXd3AqmlkixDglDJBgTEtMoXhXVyDjvJSaVUqdFTokP3YcRNhlTzqDQ3vG8txTLzECsyQHZ7DgWp%2B98P3zjvtad9xB%2BDzXhF4CaUB7ve99bWO5FO1DU3KRhx7pEAKGselDCoxTOkjIhEMMJbeQrbC1QWJ4uR9KlBPBdIbShd3\x0d
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)\x0d
Host: stream.watsonplatform.net\x0d

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\x0d
X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL\x0d
Connection: Keep-Alive\x0d
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\x0d
X-Error-Cause: Zuul Error: Malformed Session ID Cookie\x0d
Content-Type: application/json\x0d
Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 19:41:26 GMT\x0d
Server: -\x0d
X-Global-Transaction-ID: 237895544\x0d
X-DP-Watson-Tran-ID: stream-dp01-c0182762-b9fe-4533-acab-7fbeb02b63dd\x0d
```

The code is using a single instance of Mojo::UserAgent so the cookies are maintained on each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a trailing slash is the cause of this error.  The interesting part is that the "start session" POST request with the trailing slash URL will succeed and return the correct JSON data.  The next request to get the session status will fail.  Not really a code problem.  I also demonstrated the issue with curl.

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new();
$ua->proxy->detect();
$ua->inactivity_timeout(0);

# THIS URL WORKS - no trailing slash
my $start_session_url = "https://${watson_username}:${watson_password}\@stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/sessions";
# THIS URL DOES NOT WORK - with trailing slash
# my $start_session_url = "https://${watson_username}:${watson_password}\@stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/sessions/";

my $session_tx = $ua->post($start_session_url);

my $response;
my $recognize_url;

if($response = $session_tx->success) {
     print Dumper($response->json);
     $recognize_url = $response->json->{recognize};
} else {
     die "Failure to start session";
}

$recognize_url =~ s/https:\/\//https:\/\/${watson_username}:${watson_password}\@/;

# Malformed Cookie error happens here
my $status_tx = $ua->get($recognize_url);

if($response = $status_tx->success) {
    print Dumper($response->json);
} else {
    die "Failure to get session status";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when using sessions you receive a SESSIONID cookie when creating the session, that cookie you need to send back to the service on every call you make after creating the session. Please note that the value of that cookie does not equal "session_id": "836cfc64b5856712b040a0b1b3bf4237", it is a longer alphanumeric string.

btw. why are you using sessions? what is your use case? maybe you could benefit from sessionless calls (simpler) or websockets (better for live use cases)

Dani

Comment: Sessionless works fine.   I have not been able to get websockets through the firewall which is out of my control.  Since I am trying to send pieces of a recording from a mobile device, I thought the sessions might work better.  The MOJO_USERAGENT_DEBUG output above shows the SESSIONID cookie being sent on the GET request.  Maybe the "Watson-DPAT" cookie is not needed.

Comment: please make sure that the value of the SESSIONID cookie that you send on the GET matches character by character the value of the SESSIONID cookie that you get when you make the POST to create the session